# Can I use the first value of a multivalue field as another field? ("Cover" use case)

Tags: views, entities, media

My content type uses an unlimited number of images as "screenshot". 
I would like to be able to manage the FIRST screenshot of the set as the "cover" of the content type, so to define a "field_cover" and telling Drupal "The value for this field is the first value of field_screenshot".
In this way I could reference field_cover in my views for some special cases (like showing the latest mynodes in home page, using the "cover" as the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a "wrapper" field type, but you have a few options.

I've done the same myself in Views by filtering by the "delta" value, which is the individual values in a multivalue field. That way it's easy to require "delta = 0" and get the first value. This has a limitation of currently not working with arguments/contextual filters though.

A second option is the to ctools recently added support for delta values. You can render a field and set both offset, range and reversal of deltas.

Final option I can think of is [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field), which could be programmatically coded to act as field wrapper.

Comment: I didn't think of the "delta" options in filters... thank you. By now this works for me.